# Where should I put the code for functions used in Meteor.startup?

Tags: meteor

Project code:

```
// main.js
temp = new Meteor.Collection('temp');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    // client-side stuff
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    initialize(temp);
  });
}
```

I put the function `initialize` in an external script file:

```
// startup.js
function initialize(collection){
    collection.insert({'id': 42});
}
```

But where should I put this `startup.js`? I tried the `[root]`, `lib`, `[root]/server` and `[root]/server/lib` subdirectory but none of them helps. It always reports `ReferenceError: initialize is not defined`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### File Scope

```
var initialize = function(){};
function initialize(){};
```

File Scope function can be called only from within file.

Your problem is solved using :

#### Package Scope

```
initialize = function(){}
```

Package scope function can be called from any file inside this app or package.

Read more in [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#namespacing)